# What module can be used for a client side wallet in a DApp?

Tags: web3js, wallets, dapp-development

If you want to create a DApp that is a stand alone single page application, there is the need to have access to Ether.
There are serveral ways to do that:

1. Metamask accesses your geth server
2. Mist is a stand alone browser with a wallet integrated
3. MyEtherWallet is a single page application that integrates contract functionalities
4. A fourth way would be to have a *single page application* that cane generate a wallet just for your application. Then you load money on it from where ever you want.

Question: are there ready made java script wallet libraries that can be used for 4? Or do you think web3 is just enough?

Comment: The details about MyEtherWalelt embeddable wallet generation can be found here. Basically, you embed it into your page via iframe and can grab the address generated and do stuff with it. https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4gn37o/embeddable_myetherwallet_super_simple_wallet/

Comment: Like having my own contract function TX calls?

Comment: From my UI i mean...?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options:

- https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet
- MyEtherwallet is open-source and contains a wallet you could use in your app